# "Email a link" function not working- SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, hyperlink

We recently migrated from SharePoint 2007 to 2010. There are a few sites that are having issues with the "email a link" function. when you click on it- it does absolutely nothing. This function had worked after the migration & just stopped working a few days ago. I cannot figure out what has changed. These pages have not been visually upgraded to 2010 but are custom pages created by an outside vendor. The only thing I've been able to find online is to add SharePoint:SPPageManager runat=”server”/> in the head of default.master using SharePoint designer. I did this & it still isn't working. anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In researching the issue more, I realized that I missed one of the custom master pages this site collection is using. I added  to the  and now all is good.